# Rspec model tests for average rating method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I'm trying to write tests for the following method:

```
def average_rating
  reviews = self.reviews
  review_sum = reviews.inject(0) { |sum, review| sum += review.rating }
  avg_rating = (review_sum / reviews.count).to_i unless review_sum == 0
end
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
describe "#average_rating" do
it "should be nil when there are no reviews" do
  api_without_reviews = Api.new name: 'Fake API', description: 'It does something', category: 'Fake category', url: 'http://www.example.com'
  api_without_reviews.average_rating.should be_nil
end
it "should calculate average rating properly" do
  api_with_reviews = Api.new name: 'Fake API', description: 'It does something', category: 'Fake category', url: 'http://www.example.com'
  api_with_reviews.save
  api_with_reviews.reviews.create rating: Random.rand(1..5), thoughts: 'blah'
  api_with_reviews.reviews.create rating: Random.rand(1..5), thoughts: 'blah'
  average = api_with_reviews.reviews.inject(0) { |sum, review| sum += review.rating } / api_with_reviews.reviews.count
  api_with_reviews.average_rating.should eq average
end
```

end

How can I test that the review_sum variable is calculating the sum correctly, or is the method already fully tested? I'm new at rspec so any help is appreciated!

Comment: IMHO, you should avoid randomizing in tests.

Comment: In your method there doesn't seem to be a need for this line: `reviews = self.reviews`.

Comment: Another small trick: `review_sum = reviews.map(:rating).reduce(:+)`

Comment: @AaronK thanks, nice refactoring!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer directly I suggest you not to:

- Generate random value of the review rating
- Copy the method code directly to verify it. You can't score your own paper, don't you?

Instead:

- Use manually created ratings and calculate the average manually
- Verify if the method could output what you've calculated.

#### Further improvement

- Use FactoryGirl to create test objects.
- DRY the code

My version(assume FactoryGirl installed)

```
describe "API" do
  describe "average_rating" do
    # Use "before" but not "let" because this var must be clean in every example
    before { @api = FactoryGirl.create(:api) }
  
    it "should be nil when there are no reviews" do
      @api.average_rating.should be_nil
    end

    it "should calculate average rating properly" do
      [1, 5].each do |r|
        FactoryGirl.create(:review, rating: r, api: @api)
      end 
      @api.average_rating.should eq(3)
    end
  end
end

# spec/factories.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :api do
    name 'Fake API'
    description 'It does something'
    category 'Fake category'
    url 'http://www.example.com'
  end

  factory :review do
    rating rand(1..5)
    thoughts "blah"
    api   #Association: belongs_to API
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I added FactoryGirl and used your tests. Everything is passing!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install and set up factorygirl (which I'd suggest you use in the future, it can be very useful both in tests and in the dev console, where it can greatly simplify creating objects with many required attributes), here is some code for that. This also uses the new rspec syntax, where 'expect' is favored over 'should'.

```
describe "API" do
  describe "Method: average_rating" do
    before(:each) do
      @api = Api.create(:attributes => "some value")
    end

    it "is nil when there are no reviews" do
      expect( @api.average_rating ).to be_nil
    end

    it "calculates average rating properly" do 
      ratings_sum = 0
      5.times do |rating_value|
        @api.ratings << Rating.new(:rating => rating_value, :thoughts => "lorem ipsum")
        ratings_sum += rating_value
      end
      ratings_average = ratings_sum / @api.ratings.count
      expect( @api.average_rating ).to eq( ratings_average )
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need for FactoryGirl for this test. You aren't really testing anything in respect to the database. You just want to setup state for your object, then test the outcome of the method.

Based on how you setup your tests, I think you are on the right track. Using RSpec 2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3, this is how I would write the test.

```js
describe Api do

  subject(:api) { Api.new name: 'API Under Test', description: 'Testing' }

  describe "requesting the average rating" do
    context "with no reviews" do
      it { expect(api.average_rating).to be_nil }
    end

    context "with one or more reviews" do
      it "is the standard average of the review ratings rounded down" do
        api.reviews = [
          Review.new(rating: 1, thoughts: 'test review 1'),
          Review.new(rating: 2, thoughts: 'test review 2'),
          Review.new(rating: 5, thoughts: 'test review 3'),
        ]

        expect(api.average_rating).to eq 2
      end
    end
  end

end
```

A few follow up points:

- You don't have to use the inner `context`, however, it's something I do to provide more semantics on the setup (instead of what you expect the test to prove); `context` == setup, `it` == test outcome
- As of RSpec 2.11 you can use named subject instead of just a `let`. The advantage here is that you are providing semantic clues to what your object under test is
- `let` and named `subject` give you a way to define memoized variables to use across tests
- I stay away from the `@api` version of instance variables, as it gives more flexibility on  change later without updating all of your tests (see [barewords](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SSc1mQ4-Ck))
- For more information on some RSpec conventions see http://betterspecs.org/